# Does CoderPad not support rank functions in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, rank

I tried the following query:

```
select first_name,last_name,salary,rank() over (order by salary) as Rank
from employees
order by Rank
```

And I got the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by salary) as Rank
>   from employees
>   order by Rank at line 1

Comment: As the error message states, MySQL does not support window functions (prior to version 8).

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff . How does one achieve the same result as a rank in earlier versions then?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest implementation is for `row_number()`, not `rank()`.  Perhaps this will work for you:

```
select first_name, last_name, salary,
       (@rn := @rn + 1) as Rank
from employees e cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
order by salary;
```

If you specifically need `rank()` that is a little trickier.